# .net Error getting when trying to get auth token using Oauth2

Tags: .net, api, rest

I am new to the Oauth2 concept. I am trying to connect to API. The API requires me to get a token code with client credentials. I am using the library RestSharp to connect. I am using the code below and getting the following error: `Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.`

Below is my code:

```
        Dim Url As String = "https://api.site.com:21443/api/auth"
        Dim client_id As String = "ID"
        Dim client_secret As String = "SECRET"

        Dim rClient As New RestClient(Url)
        Dim rRequest As New RestRequest(Method.Post)
        rRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json")


        rRequest.AddParameter("client_id", client_id)
        rRequest.AddParameter("client_secret", client_secret)
        rRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials")

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Dim tResponse As RestResponse = rClient.Execute(rRequest)
        Dim responseJson As String = tResponse.Content
```

I code above is something I found on the web. I obviously do not understand, but I do need some help. How can I get the token using client credentials grant type.

Comment: You should use an OAuth2 helper library instead of doing it yourself, because there's a _lot_ of things to consider (e.g. refresh tokens, PKCE, etc): https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/ https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel

Comment: Is there sample code?